# Mysql, acess denied for user, using password: no

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Ao criar um novo projeto no rails usando o mysql

```
rails new exemplo -d mysql
```

e depois

```
rake db:create
```

tenho o seguinte erro

```
Acess denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: NO) Please provide root password for your MySQL instalation
```

Então ele pede a senha do meu mysql, eu coloco e continua dando o mesmo erro, mesmo conseguindo conectar no banco de dados pelo terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Foi resolvido o problema colocando usuário e senha do banco de dados no arquivo database.yml, na pasta config do meu projeto **teste**:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/teste/config/database.yml
```